# How to switch a transistor when a radio signal is received?

Tags: diy, receiver, remote-control, transmitter

I have a circuit which switches on by sending current to the base of one of its transistors. I'm trying to make receiver which can receive signals from a AM transmitter and send current to base of transistor so that circuit can switch on the circuit. I know how can I make AM transmitter. Given that I cannot use any receiver module/chip etc, please suggest a simple circuit design which can serve the purpose.

EDIT: I need a receiver with minimum range of **500-700meters**. I have made [this AM transmitter](http://www.circuitstoday.com/long-range-am-transmitter). As stated above I'm not trying to send audio signals, the circuit stays on as longs as current is passing through base of transistor. I want the circuit to stay on as long as transmitter is sending signals to receiver. What modifications I have to make in transmitter circuit for that.

Comment: As you can see from the answers, your question it is very broad. Please specify the transmission EIRP and distance bertween Rx and Tx to get more pricise answer

Comment: The question hasn't got any better by just adding the range without transmitter details as above, frequency, how it's modulated and generally what you're trying to do.

Comment: Added a link of my transmitter design.

Comment: If you are not planning to transmit an audio signal, do you mean to say you just want a circuit to detect the presence of the unmodulated carrier from your transmitter?